# QML on Linux: make the window stay on top of all applications

Tags: linux, qt, qml, window

**Ubuntu 23.04 x86_64**

I'm trying to create secondary window that will stay **always on top of all applications and will not close after I close/minimize parent window**.

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Window
import QtQuick.Controls

ApplicationWindow {
    id: root

    width: 600
    height: 600

    visible: true

    Window {
        id: innerWindow

        width: 200
        height: 200

        visible: true

        flags: Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint | Qt.FramelessWindowHint
    }
}
```

For my issue this code works great on Windows OS, but on Linux it doesn't.

Also I tried to create window like Component and QtObject property. Secondary window always behaves like a parent window and only stay on top of it even with **Qt.X11BypassWindowManagerHint** flag.

**EDIT:** To make secondary window independent from parent's behavior I just create it like QtObject property inside parent window. But this window still don't stay on top of all applications, I may use **Atl+Space** to invoke standard linux window menu and set *Stay on top*, but I want to make it by standard.

Answer (score 0):

[WindowFlags docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#windowFlags-prop)

Have you tried calling show() after?